# Сделать рамку в div используя ::after

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно, чтобы была дополнительная рамка, в которую можно было бы потом запихнуть еще контент. У меня её не вышло выровнять. Вот код.

```css
div.preview-box {position: absolute; width: 70px; height: 60px; background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0,0,0, 0.86)); 
border: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 0px;}
div.preview-box::after {content: ""; border: 2px solid #343333; position: fixed; width: 68px; height: 58px;}
```

```html
<div class="preview-box"></div>
```

То есть надо, чтобы рамка была центрирована и с отступами по `1px` от каждой стороны.

Comment: Так вроде все работает...

Comment: @AndreyFedorov  Она не по центру родителя.

Comment: Ладно, сейчас сделаем...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `box-shadow`

```css
div.preview-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px tomato; /* для примера */
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-box"></div>
```

Comment: С телефона глянуть не могу. Сори.

Comment: Классный вариант. Мне понравился! 

Answer (score 3):

```css
div.preview-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.preview-box::after {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid red; // #343333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-box"></div>
```